# AES encryption, what is better Javascript or Php

Tags: php, javascript, aes

What is more secure for a web application to implement an AES Encryption in PHP or Javascript ?

I am more comfortable with PHP and I want to use a symmetric algorithm for a simple form where a user can encrypt and store in a database a textblock &/or file.

The user can retrieve later the text or File using the same key.

Implementing AES with PHP POST / GET can be vulnerable for attacks ?

Is it better to provide users with a SHA-256 ( Key ) ?

Can someone provide a good online implementation of a correct AES encryption for thsi kind of task.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/  http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/

Comment: Security is **hard**.  You cannot create a secure system without learning a lot more about cryptography.

Comment: Huh? How can the same algorithm be more secure if implemented in another language?

Comment: Why would you use JS to encrypt anything? What's the point?

Comment: @N.B.: Then the user does not have to trust the server to keep the key secret.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The algorithm is the same, but key management is different (does the user have it or the service provider)?

Comment: The key is only provided to the users. That s a good point, if using a shared hosting and someone can access the file systems then the whole security is useless.
@Jan Dvorak, I understand the algorithm is the same but some developer say that Javascript can be more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference seems to be whether the user (browser) encrypts the data, or you (server).

With client-side encryption, it is possible to have a "trust-no-one" system where the server operator cannot access the user's data. Of course, this also makes it impossible to recover lost keys, and to provide search or sharing services.

But see @SLaks' comments about the fact that you cannot be secure if you blindly trust the Javascript that the web site sends you. A vetted and signed native client app could be a better (but less convenient) solution if this is really important.

Comment: User privacy is first. I want the encryption to occur at the stage less vulnerable and I do not mind that the server operator cannot read the user's data. As for the lost keys and provide search is not mandatory. I want simply a user's vault. he stores a text, receive a key. and only person with that key can read the text.

Comment: `With client-side encryption, it is possible to have a "trust-no-one" system`.  Nope.  The user must trust every bit of JS running in the page (including analytics stuff), as well as every browser extension.

Comment: @SLaks: Well, he could vet it in theory. Analytics in particular is trivial to block. But yeah, it's a problem, the "Javascript trap". http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html

Comment: @Thilo: No; he's still vulnerable to anyone with write access to his server or CDNs.

Comment: @SLaks: Cryptographic digests of the Javascript can prevent it from being messed with after they have been vetted.

Comment: @Thilo: No, because there is no trusted code that can do that vetting (or store the hash)

Comment: @SLaks: Well, you'd need to trust your browser to do that. Same as it does with SSL certificates. I am well aware that this is not a functionality mainstream browsers offer.